# How to remove directories from final build zip archive using maven 3

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho, maven-ant-tasks

When the build is ready i have p2 folder in all build archives for different platforms.As i understand it's imposible to exclude p2 directory from archives on building stage. So I try pack archive myself instead of using archive-products execution.
The problem is if i want to make archives for others platform or architecture I will need to change pom.
Now i have the following build schema:

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>materialize-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pack-zip-files</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <zip basedir="${project.build.directory}/products/xxx/win32/win32/x86"
                                    destfile="${project.build.directory}/products/xxx-1.0.${BUILD_NUMBER}-win32.win32.x86.zip"
                                    excludes="${exclude_p2}" />
                                <zip basedir="${project.build.directory}/products/xxx/linux/gtk/x86"
                                    destfile="${project.build.directory}/products/xxx-1.0.${BUILD_NUMBER}-linux.gtk.x86.zip"
                                    excludes="${exclude_p2}" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

The quiestion is how to remove p2 folder from all zip files?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing now is really the only way to do it. You could change the packaging type to `eclipse-application` and that directory won't be created, but it is a deprecated packaging type and has a whole slew of problems.

The only way to help with multiple POM support would be to put that POM configuration into a profile and have your projects that build products inherit from it. You can also use the `osgi.os` `osgi.arch` properties in place of hard-coding things like `win32` and `linux`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what if use  archive-products and after archives will be ready extract content from each .zip archive to folder with archive name and after repack it. Is it possible to get name of current handled archive/folder with maven? (i understand that it is not perfect solution but from my point of view it will be more flexible).